# Force GtkListStore to align column right

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

What is the best (or any way) to force GtkCellRenderer to align columns right? I've managed to find a piece about it in the documentation of gtk2.0 - under [this](https://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/gtk/GtkCellRendererText.html#GtkCellRendererText--alignment) link PANGO_ALIGN_LEFT is mentioned as default setting for "alignment" property and although it should work it doesn't. Through analogy there should exist a constant of name PANGO_ALIGN_RIGHT and (if working) this should solve my problem. While searching through gtk source code I came across 0.0 and 1.0 options as possible settings for "alignment" but this didn't work either.

```
(gtklistview_right:25878): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:17:15.109: unable to set property 'alignment' of type 'PangoAlignment' from value of type 'gchararray'
```

Code:

gtklistview_right.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

enum {

  LIST_ITEM = 0,
  N_COLUMNS
};

void init_list(GtkWidget *list) {

  GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column;
  GtkListStore *store;

  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("List Items", renderer, 
    "text", LIST_ITEM,
    "alignment", PANGO_ALIGN_LEFT, 
    NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), column);

  store = gtk_list_store_new(N_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING);

  gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), 
      GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));

  g_object_unref(store);
}

void add_to_list(GtkWidget *list, const gchar *str) {
    
  GtkListStore *store;
  GtkTreeIter iter;

  store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model
      (GTK_TREE_VIEW(list)));

  gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
  gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, LIST_ITEM, str, -1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *list;

  GtkWidget *vbox;
  GtkWidget *label;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  list = gtk_tree_view_new();

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "List view");
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 270, 250);

  gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), FALSE);

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), list, TRUE, TRUE, 5);

  label = gtk_label_new("");
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 5);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  init_list(list);
  add_to_list(list, "Aliens");
  add_to_list(list, "Leon");
  add_to_list(list, "The Verdict");
  add_to_list(list, "North Face");
  add_to_list(list, "Der Untergang");

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
LIBS=`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
PROGRAMS=gtklistview_right
SRC=gtklistview_right.c

all: $(PROGRAMS)

%: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm $(PROGRAMS)
```

Comment: g_object_set ( G_OBJECT ( renderer ), "xalign", 1.0F, NULL );

Answer (score 1):

You are using the 'alignment' property which aligns the lines of text in case there are several of them. To align all the text, use the 'xalign' property.

And the docs are https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererText.html#GtkCellRendererText--alignment